# IOS Swift, how to detect file upload click inside UIWebView to open photo upload dialog

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have an app that points to a website using a UIWebView. The website includes a file input for uploading photos. When the user taps the file upload button inside the website it should open the photo upload dialog on the iPhone, so you can upload a photo directly from the phone to the website. How do you detect the file upload button click and open the photo upload dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You only need the html file upload tag

```
<input type="file" name="img">
```

UIWebView automatically opens the upload photo dialog, I think its the only way.